# dynamic variable name to make uibutton (swift)

Tags: swift

How to create dynamic variable name to make uibutton

```
 var button0 = SSRadiobutton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,50))
 var button1 = SSRadiobutton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,50))
 var button2 = SSRadiobutton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,50))
 var button3 = SSRadiobutton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,50))
```

Actually there is a tutorial called SSRadiobutton.

```
radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons:button0,button1,button2)
```

there is a button array inside ssradiobuttonscontroller to store the buttons so that it can perform single selection.

but the question is that i have to initialise the ssradiobuttonscontroller with dynamic name. the names can't be same

Comment: What is the purpose of dynamic variable name? If you want to add more buttons on view, you must use loop or something... Which do not require to name your variable like this

Comment: i am creating a tableview. i have to add subview of the button for each cell corresponding to their index path.row

Comment: You can also set button tag according to the indexPath.row. When the button method called match the tag to get the indexPath.row

Comment: its hard to explain here. but i really need to create it

Comment: but then how to add subview of the button for each cell corresponding to their index path.row.   for example, index path.row =0, it should add subview of button0

Comment: Do every button doing different task or same task?

Comment: i will add more detail now. thanks for helping